# Changing footnotes/endnotes into hidden comments or annotations

Tags: xetex, footnotes, comments, annotations

So I have a rather large dissertation that currently contains footnotes and endnotes (using  `\makepagenote`). The final document can only contain footnotes. Some of the `\pagenote{ ... }` material will become `\footnote`, but there are others that I don't want to appear in the final PDF but retain in the `.tex` file for future reference. I tried search and replace `\pagenote{` to `%`, but the end of the comment is hard to determine.

I'm using scrivener to generate the `.tex` document, so I could change the closing bracket `}` for endnotes to be whatever I want to make search/replace easier, except "enter". Since I use TexShop to generate my PDF's, it relies on OgreKit which can use regular expression search/replace, but I have no idea how that works. The other thing I've found is using a comments/annotations package, but there seems to be quite a few and my first attempt was unsuccessful with XeLaTeX.

Comment: Does `\renewcommand{\pagenote}[1]{}` in the preamble, right before `\begin{document}` work?

Comment: or `\renewcommand{\pagenote}[1]{\pdfcomment[icon=Comment]{#1}}` with `\usepackage{pdfcomment}` in the preamble